# JPA persisting twice

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans

I'm trying to save into a MySQL database a entity that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "logistic", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Movement.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Movement m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Movement.findByIdMovement", query = "SELECT m FROM Movement m WHERE m.idMovement = :idMovement"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Movement.findByQty", query = "SELECT m FROM Movement m WHERE m.qty = :qty"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Movement.findByDt", query = "SELECT m FROM Movement m WHERE m.dt = :dt")})
public class Movement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_movement", nullable = false)
    private Long idMovement;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int qty;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dt;
    @JoinColumn(name = "from_id_container", referencedColumnName = "id_container", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Container fromIdContainer;
    @JoinColumn(name = "to_id_container", referencedColumnName = "id_container", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Container toIdContainer;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_product", referencedColumnName = "id_product", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product idProduct;
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User username;
// Getters and setters...
```

This entity has been generated by netbeans. The problem is that when I try to persist data into the database, it inserts two files instead of one. The code I use to persis the data is

```
Movement movement = new com.pccomponentes.sga.entity.Movement();
movement.setFromIdContainer(from);
movement.setToIdContainer(to);
movement.setIdProduct(product);
movement.setQty(obj.getInt("qty"));
movement.setUsername(userEJB.find(redis.get("token-" + token)));
movementEJB.create(movement);
```

What's happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you enable logging and check what's happening?

Comment: Honestly, this is the first time I use Java (I come from PHP) and I don't know how to enable loggin. Thanks!

Comment: Then u should learn java before doing some stuffs like this. otherwise u may be in trouble

Comment: as well as check if ur code is running twice so it's persisting dual entries

Comment: Finally, the REST client I was using was sending two requests instead of one... Always the silliest thing is the answer....